# Can't get PayPal access token for live environment

Tags: authentication, paypal

I need to get a PayPal access token and use it for webhook verification. During my testing period (using sandbox environment) there weren't issues, I called https://api.sandbox.paypal.com/v1/oauth2/token with basic authentication and paypal exchanged credentials. But now I need to go into production, therefore I need a live access token (no more sandbox) and using EXACTLY THE SAME METHOD, simply changing clientId and clientSecret for live environment of course, PayPal API is answering with

> { error": "invalid_client",
>       "error_description": "Client Authentication failed" }

How can I do to overcome this authentication problem?

Comment: Can we rule out all the items from this list: https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/wiki/Going-Live ?

Comment: @DaemonPainter yes, I've done all those steps

Answer (score 1):

The problem actually wasn't a problem. I was calling api.SANDBOX.paypal.com for live environment. Of course it wasn't working: I need to call api.paypal.com. The previous call was for sandbox environments only.